# Understanding the differences between Debug and Release builds of an UWP IoT Core app

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I have a solution for an UWP app targeting Win 16299. There are 5 projects in it. 3 are test projects, one library and one UWP app.

In Debug the build takes less than 20 seconds.

```
5>Time Elapsed 00:00:10.04
========== Rebuild All: 5 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

In Release the build takes

```
5>Time Elapsed 00:04:01.13
========== Rebuild All: 5 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Looking at detailed output of the build I can see that this is connected with 'native compilation' and it, perhaps not surprisingly, requires a lot more computation.

What are some references to educate myself and understand the differences better?

Comment: Do you have "Compile with .Net Native tool chain" option enabled in your project file?

Comment: "Compile with .NET Native tool chain" is on for Release and off for Debug.

Answer (score 4):

The main differences between Debug and Release builds are the *Compile with .NET Native tool chain* and *Optimize* code switched in the project's Build properties tab.

[image]

I found these two articles on learn.microsoft.com:

1. [.NET Native and Compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/net-native-and-compilation), and
2. [Compiling Apps with .NET Native](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/)

This article was also useful: [.NET Native – What it means for Universal Windows Platform (UWP) developers](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/08/20/net-native-what-it-means-for-universal-windows-platform-uwp-developers/) and here is a quote from it.

> **How does .NET Native impact me and my app?**
>
> Your mileage likely will vary, but for most cases your app will start up faster, perform better, and consume fewer system resources.
>
> - Up to 60% performance improvement on cold startup times
> - Up to 40% performance improvement on warm startup times
> - Less memory consumption of your app when compiled natively
> - No dependencies on the desktop .NET Runtime installed on the system
> - Since your app is compiled natively, you get the performance benefits associated with native code (think C++ performance)
> - You can still take advantage of the industry-leading C# or VB programming languages, and the tools associated with them
> - You can continue to use the comprehensive and consistent programming model available with .NET– with extensive APIs to write
>     business logic, built-in memory management, and exception handling.

Comment: Glad to know that you found the answer.

Comment: @tymtam You can accept this as answer if you think it answers your question.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Since it's my answer I need to wait 2 days.

Comment: @tymtam Ok. Thanks.